# Jetty - Virtualhosting - SSL Certificates

Tags: ssl-certificate, virtualhost, jboss, jetty

I want to have different SSL certificates for different domains that I am hosting in a single Jetty instance.

I do not want to front my Jetty application server with Apache.

I am running Jetty 6.1.22.  So far, I have only seen configurations with a single SSL certificate, and the configuration for SSL happens within server which leads me to believe that Jetty was designed to support a single SSL certificate.

Please let me know if I can use Jetty with more than 1 certificate.

I am considering migrating to JBoss Application Server 6.0 since it is closer to a real application server.  Is this something that can be done there, and is it a supported feature?

After searching a little bit, I came across this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208149/configure-multiple-keystores-in-jboss-depending-on-requested-hostname

Is that the case?  If so, then I doubt Jetty or any other application server would support it.  I would need to have 2 different connectors - different port or ip address.  Then, I would need to have Apache proxy Jetty / JBoss in that case.

Walter

Comment: Yes, you would need a different socket (address+port) for each unique certificate you wanted to use.  I am not sure what that means from the perspective of Jetty.

Answer (score 3):

Did you read the Jetty documentation?

Glassfish does it by attaching the certificates to the HTTP(S) listeners, which are then in turn bound to a server instance.

According to the documentation, the way Jetty does it is pretty similar:
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Virtual+hosts

You simply configure your vhosts (make them IP based, SSL is negotiated before host headers are ever sent), and then add multiple connectors, one per IP/HTTPS connector. Each can have its own trust/keystore with the SSL certificate in them.

https://web.archive.org/web/20150509123728/http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Ssl+Connector+Guide
newer: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html

Simply add a connector per certificate. There's no way around it, SSL requires a dedicated IP address, so one connector per SSL site you wish to serve.

According to this document:
https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/configuring-connectors.html

The "host" directive for connectors will allow you to bind them to a specific address, thus solving your problem.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Because I've now spent some time going through Jetty Documentation:

**With Java 8 (which can do SNI), you don't need to configure *anything* in order to serve multiple different HTTPS certificates.** They only need to be in your keystore. Jetty will automatically choose the right one, depending on the hostname used when connecting.